# How does android use hilt to inject activity viewmodel in fragment viewmodel?

Tags: mvvm

I'm developing an android app using mvvm and hilt, I need to use activity viewmodel in fragment viewmodel, does anyone know how to inject activity viewmodel in fragment viewmodel using hilt? Thank you so much! !